# Kotlin Coroutines - How to check dispatcher in unit testing

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class that takes a coroutine dispatcher as a constructor parameter.

```
class Test(
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    private val foo: Foo, // Just another arg
) {
    fun test() {
        // Does stuff
    }
}
```

This dispatcher is used in certain points in the `test()` method using `withContext(dispatcher)`.

To unit test this class, I pass a `StandardTestDispatcher` instance for the dispatcher parameter.

```
val mainTestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
val testSubject = Test(
    dispatcher = mainTestDispatcher,
    foo = mockk(), // I'm using MockK for these mocks
)
```

Now I want to make sure `Foo` methods are being called using this dispatcher, and I can't figure out how to do this.

I tried the following (based on other answers I've found):

```
    @Test
    fun test() {
        every { foo.bar() } coAnswers {
            val dispatcher = coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]!!
            dispatcher shouldBe mainTestDispatcher
        }
        runTest(standardTestDispatcher) {
            testSubject.test().shouldBeNull()
        }
    }
```

But this `dispatcher` is not `standardTestDispatcher` but a `BlockingEventLoop` instance.

Comment: `coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]` retrieves the `ContinuationInterceptor` from the scope's context, so you do not compare `CoroutineDispatcher` types directly. However, dispatchers implement `ContinuationInterceptor` and so does `BlockingEventLoop`, so it make sense to compare them. `BlockingEventLoop` may indicate that there was no dispatcher assigned, probably by just creating a scope with `runBlocking`. Where does your scope come from? It should be `runTest`.

Comment: @Leviathan Right, missing the actual test, I've updated the question with the actual test function and more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BackUpManager @Inject constructor(
        private val inventoryRepository: InventoryRepository,
        private val soldItemsRepository: SoldItemsRepository,
        private val firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage,
        private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    ) {
        private var backupJob: Job? = null
        private var uploadTask: UploadTask? = null
    
    
        private val inventoryItems = inventoryRepository.getAllInventoryItems()
        private val soldItems = soldItemsRepository.getAllSoldItems()
    
        private fun commenceBackUp() {
            backupJob = CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
                
            }
        }
        
        private fun cancelBackUp() = backupJob?.cancel()
    
    }
```

Why not assign the coroutine to a job, then you can assign the work you want to a coroutine and also cancel it when not needed, this will insure that only that coroutine will be used.
The sample code above was gotten from one of my projects

Comment: I want to check which dispatcher is used, not which coroutine.